# Firefox 3.5.3 Windows + Flash + swfobject wmode problem

Tags: flash, firefox, swfobject, transparent, wmode

I'm having issues with Firefox 3.5.3 Windows embedding Flash using wmode.

If I set the wmode parameter to 'transparent' or 'opaque' Firefox 3.5.3 Win XP (Flash player 10.0.32.18 r32) completely fails to embed the movie, but it works in everything else, including IE on the same machine and the same FF in Mac OS.

Can anyone help please?

I put together a test page of this issue here. If it works you should see a video player and streaming movie.

http://mutualsforum.wanderingbear.co.uk/flashtest.html

Thanks

Comment: It is working on my FF3(ver 3.5.5) on windows xp(sp3)

Answer (score 0):

I really despise SWFObject for this very reason. Maybe you could give [FlowPlayer](http://flowplayer.org/) a try

Answer (score 0):

Flowplayer isn't an option unfortunately.

The only way I could get this to work was to steal the YouTube non-compliant embed code and edit it a bit. Not ideal at all!

Comment: This doesn't work. It's very temperamental works about 1 refresh in 10.

Going out of my mind!